# gnuplot: simple beeswarm example

Tags: gnuplot

I have been struggling with a basic beeswarm plot from page 62 in [this doc](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.4/Gnuplot_5_4.pdf). I imagine they are skipping some details, and I'm not sure what actual data they used. I think in particular the problem is mapping a categorical/string variable to an X-axis value.

I used this data:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 4
B 5
B 6
```

With this script:

```
set terminal png
set output "graph.png"
set jitter
plot "data.csv" using 1:2:1 with points lc variable
```

I get this error:

```
"graph_script" line 4: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

plot "data.csv" using 1:2:1 with points lc variable
                                                   ^
"graph_script" line 4: x range is invalid
```

In their demos gallery, I see something like `set xtics ("A" -1, "B" 0)` which could maybe help me to label already-numeric data better, but what if my data doesn't start off numeric to begin with?

Do I need something like `(hash_string_to_large_int($1) % 2)`? There must be an easier way!

Comment: yes, the example your are mentioning is skipping some essential details. `using 1:2` requires numerical values in column 1 and column 2. gnuplot cannot plot characters or strings as x-coordinates. It can, if you "assign" a number to your characters, e.g. A=1, B=2, etc. Depending on how your real data looks like, it can be done automatically or you can write some gnuplot code which does that for you. So, how does your real data look like?

Comment: @theozh, well, I'm curious how one might do it for a large number of categories without too much manual mapping, though even a manual mapping would be helpful. In my original case, I was plotting the number of lines by file extension in some source code, e.g. `.py 15, .py 100, .sh 25, .html 40` etc, and I wanted 3 clusters of points, 1 for each file type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you have to "convert" your keys into numbers in order to plot them.
You can do this by creating a list with your unique keywords and defining a function to get the indices.

- First, the following example creates some random data
- The code after knows nothing about the keywords, so it creates the unique list from scratch from the random data.

Maybe there is (and I am not aware) a simpler solution with gnuplot only.

**Code:**

```
### bee-swarm plot with string keys
reset session

# create some random test data
myExts = '.py .sh .html'
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:100] {
        print sprintf("%s %d",word(myExts,int(rand(0)*3)+1),int(rand(0)*10+1)*5)
    }
set print

# create a unique list of strings from a data stringcolumn
Uniques = ''
addToList(list,col) = list.( strstrt(list,'"'.strcol(col).'"') > 0 ? '' : ' "'.strcol(col).'"')
stats $Data u (Uniques = addToList(Uniques,1),0) nooutput

getIdx(key) = (_idx=NaN, sum [_i=1:words(Uniques)] (word(Uniques,_i) eq key ? _idx=_i : 0), _idx)

set offsets 0.5,0.5,1,1
set key noautotitle

set multiplot layout 1,2

    set title "No jitter"
    plot $Data u (idx=getIdx(strcol(1))):2:(idx):xtic(word(Uniques,idx)) w points pt 7 lc var

    set title "With jitter"
    set jitter
    replot
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a nice generic solution. Will keep digesting. Is there also some way to explicitly say "treat `.py` as 0, `.sh` as 1, and `.html` as 2"?

Comment: @dcc310 if you know your keywords beforehand, you can skip the creation of `Uniques` and simply define `Uniques = '.py .sh .html'`, then `.py` would be 1, `.sh` would be 2 and `.html` would be 3.